# How I can reload tableview data after the animation of fade swipeAction completed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

I use SwipeCellKit for do swipe actions for my tableview.
I try to do the left swipe for check or unckech for accessoryType of my cell and everything work fine, but after i press check the tableview reload the data immediatelly and i can't see the animation of roollback the check button. So i want to ask how i can call reload data after this animation end.

I have something like this:

[I have something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De0NP.gif)

But i want fade animation like this

[I want this animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6n1g.gif)

My code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
    var action = super.tableView(tableView, editActionsForRowAt: indexPath, for: orientation) ?? []

    guard orientation == .left else { return action }

    let checkAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: nil) { action, indexPath in     

        self.completeItem(at: indexPath)

    }
    action.append(checkAction)
    return action

}



private func completeItem(at indexPath: IndexPath){
    if let item = itemArray?[indexPath.row]{

        do{
            try realm.write {
                item.done = !item.done
            }

        }

        catch{

            print( error.localizedDescription)

        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: Use SwipeTableViewCellDelegate

Comment: And read documentation https://swipecellkit.github.io/SwipeCellKit/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide the action on select, you need to set the hidesWhenSelected property for the action.

```
checkAction.hidesWhenSelected = true
```

Also, the example doesn't reload the tableView. Instead, they use an animation to remove the dot. You will need to manually delay your reload until the hide animation is complete.

See line 156 for the property

See lines 256 - 273 for the animation
https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit/blob/develop/Example/MailExample/MailTableViewController.swift

Comment: I tried to do something like lines 256 - 273 for the animation, but in their example, haw i understand, they do another animation of the own baloon type of IndicatorView. But for my task i work with property of tableView cell. It's accessoryType and i don't understand how i can do this for mu task.

Comment: I believe you can still animate your accessoryType for uitableviewcell.